# How to print the structure of an R object to the console

Tags: r

What is the command for printing the structure of R objects so the object can be re-created by running the printed output?

The output often contains the `structure` function, and you can copy and paste the output into your code in order to easily create an object for a reproducible example.

I'm breaking my head all morning over this command that I ought to know.

Comment: This is a good question and discovering `dput` has been very helpful, but the wording of this question makes it hard to find via google as it does not come up with searches like "Print R object that so that it can be copy and pasted into your code".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The function is `dput` (or `dump`).

Answer (score 18):

I think `str` function (aka structure) has more consistently useful information than dump.

From the R help:

```
Compactly Display the Structure of an Arbitrary R Object

Description


Compactly display the internal structure of an R object, a diagnostic function and an 
alternative to summary (and to some extent, dput). Ideally, only one line for each 
‘basic’ structure is displayed. It is especially well suited to compactly display the 
(abbreviated) contents of (possibly nested) lists. The idea is to give reasonable 
output for any R object. It calls args for (non-primitive) function objects.
```

Comment: This is awesome.

Comment: As a convenience, RStudio's "Environment" tab displays the output of `str`.