# Saving R objects (code) in .R files (R genetic programming)

Tags: r

I'm using R for genetic programming with the RGP package. The environment creates functions that solve problems. I want to save these functions in their own .R source files. I can't for the life of me figure out how. One way I've tried is this:

```
bf_str = print(bf)
save(bf_str,file="MyBestFunction.R"))
```

bf is simply the best fit function. I've tried it also like this:

```
save(bf,file="MyBestFunction.R"))
```

The outputted file is super weird. Its just a bunch of crazy characters

Comment: Related to [R: Turning RData file into script files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835714/r-turning-rdata-file-into-script-files) and [How to print the structure of an R object to the console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991393/how-to-print-the-structure-of-an-r-object-to-the-console/9991460).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I understand your question, you'd like to get a text representation of the functions and save that to a file. To do that, you can divert the output of the R console using the `sink` function.

```
sink(file="MyBestFunction.R")
bf_str
sink()
```

Then you can `source` the file or open it using R or another program via your OS.

**EDIT:**

To append a comment to the end of the file, you could do the following:

```
theScore <- .876

sink(file = "MyBestFunction.R", append = TRUE)
cat("# This was a great function with a score of", theScore, "\r\n")
sink()
```

Depending on your setup, you might need to change `\r\n` to reflect the appropriate end of line characters. This should work on DOS/Windows at least.

Comment: Ah.  That's not how I read the question, but I bet you're right.

Comment: @GSee, the "just a bunch of crazy characters" part suggested that maybe plain text is the goal. But we'll see...

Comment: Option 1 works, but this also looks good. I'd love a way to output some more text in the file in a comment, specifically its score... Thanks

Comment: @ZekeAlexandreNierenberg, There are a few ways to include comments in the file. One way to do it is added as an edit above. It might be helpful to include a small working example if this isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: @ZekeAlexandreNierenberg: you should have added that extra requirement to your question.  It would have given others a chance to respond, instead of only the one answer you commented on.  I have added a solution to your extra requirement to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, still learning Stack Overflow etiquette. Didn't know that was a question when I posted. Your solution is very tidy.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `dump` for this.  It will save the assignment and the definition so you can `source` it later.

```
R> f <- function(x) x*2
R> dump("f")
R> rm(f)
R> source("dumpdata.R")
R> f
function(x) x*2
```

Update to respond to the OP's additional request in the comments of another answer:

You can add attributes to your function to store whatever you want.  You could add a `score` attribute:

```
R> f <- function(x) x*2
R> attr(f, 'score') <- 0.876
R> dump("f")
R> rm(f)
R> source("dumpdata.R")
R> f
function(x) x*2
attr(,"score")
[1] 0.876
R> readLines("dumpdata.R")
[1] "f <-"                                     
[2] "structure(function(x) x*2, score = 0.876)"
```

Comment: Much better. Keeps the assignment. Shorter.

Answer (score 3):

While the question has already been answered, I should mention that `dump` has some pitfalls and IMO you would be better off saving your function in binary format via `save`.

In particular, `dump` only saves the function code itself, *not* any associated environment. This may not be a problem here, but could bite you at some point. For example, suppose we have

```
e <- new.env()
e$x <- 10
f <- function(y) y + x
environment(f) <- e
```

Then `dump("f")` will only save the function definition of `f`, and not its environment. If you then `source` the resulting file, `f` will no longer work correctly. This doesn't happen if you use `save` and `load`.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `save` the names of objects to be saved via the `list` argument

```
save(list="bf_str", file="MyBestFunction.R")
```

Alternatively, you could use dput

```
dput(bf_str, file='MyFun.R')
```

and `dget` to retrieve

```
bf_str <- dget("MyFun.R")
```