# R: Save all functions within environment as a "txt" (notepad) file

Tags: r, function, environment-variables, save, export

I am using the R programming language.

Suppose I defined 3 functions within the environment :

```
#function 1
function_1 <- function(x1, x2) {
    var_1 <- sin(x1 + x2)
    var_2 <- cos(x1 - x2)
    goal_1 = sum(var_1 + var_2)
    return(goal_1)
    
}

#function 2
function_2 <- function(x1, x2) {
    var_1 <- sin(x1 + x2)
    var_2 <- cos(x1 - x2)
    goal_1 = sum(var_1 - var_2)
    return(goal_1)
    
}

#function 3

function_3 <- function(x1, x2) {
    var_1 <- sin(x1 + x2)
    var_2 <- cos(x1 - x2)
    goal_1 = sum(var_1 * var_2)
    return(goal_1)
    
}
```

I found this stackoverflow post ([Save all functions in an txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462469/save-all-functions-in-an-txt-file)) which shows how to take all functions within the environment and save them as an "rds" fileL

```
#save everything within the environment as a "rds" file:

dump(lsf.str(), file="essay_4_code.R")
```

But is there anything which can directly save these functions as a txt/notepad file? I know that I can just open this file ("essay_4_code.R") in R, then copy/paste all the text into a notepad file, and then save the notepad file - but is there anything which would allow me to do this directly?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `dump(lsf.str(), file="essay_4_code.txt")` ?

Comment: @RonakShah : thank you! I thought for some reason "lsf.str" only handles "R" files. this worked perfectly! thank you!

Comment: would you like to write an answer so that future readers will know immediately how to solve this problem? if not, let me know, and i can do it. thank you for your help!

Comment: You can add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by @RonakShah:

```
dump(lsf.str(), file="essay_4_code.txt")
```